# AngularJs having Issues getting onblur to work correctly when input field is left empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm working on a form to input data, currently when a user inputs a number, then deletes it and moves from the input field it will display the error message span. I want it to display if a user clicks into the field then clicks out without adding a number in. I'm not sure why the onblur isn't working as that's how it was done in two tutorials I found.

```
<form name="myform" novalidate>
        <table class="text-center margin-top">
            <tr>
                <th class="header">Course Type</th>
                <th>Amount of Times</th>
                <th>Frequency (PA)</th>
                <th>% Staff who need it</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="header"><label for="induction">Induction:</label></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" id="inductionAmount" name="inductionAmount" ng-model="staff.inductionAmount" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-required="true" /></td>
                <span class="error-message" ng-show="!myform.inductionAmount.$pristine && myform.inductionAmount.$error.required">Please enter an induction value</span>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" id="inductionFrequency" name="inductionFrequency" ng-model="staff.inductionFrequency" ng-required="true" /></td>
                <span class="error-message" ng-show="myform.inductionFrequency.$dirty && myform.inductionFrequency.$error.required">Please enter an induction value</span>          
                <td><p>100</p></td>             
            </tr>       
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="row margin-top">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myform.$invalid" class="button-orange" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700;" ng-click="clicked()">Next Step</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as @user2341963 stated, `ng-model-options` wasn't a feature of angular 1.2.  Instead of trying to come up with a workaround, though, you should probably think about why you are trying to use a deprecated 3 year old version instead of a recent update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it to display if a user clicks into the field then clicks out without adding a number in.

In this case, you can check for [`$touched`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$touched) instead of `!$pristine`:

> True if control has lost focus.

This has been around since at least v1.3.20. The input only becomes not pristine or dirty if the user has interacted with the input i.e. made a change.

```
<span class="error-message" ng-show="myform.inductionAmount.$touched && myform.inductionAmount.$error.required">Please enter an induction value</span>
```

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DRAG2JGzkOxEv35equ85?p=preview).

**EDIT**

If you're using and older version then you can mimic this behaviour with the [`ngBlur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) directive `ng-blur="myform.inductionAmount.$touched=true"`

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" id="inductionAmount" name="inductionAmount" ng-model="staff.inductionAmount" ng-required="true" ng-blur="myform.inductionAmount.$touched=true"/></td>
<span class="error-message" ng-show="myform.inductionAmount.$touched && myform.inductionAmount.$error.required">Please enter an induction value</span>
```

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6fovqPML8DxYuAQNKlU6?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry! I'm using Angular 1.2... should have mentioned that.

Comment: @theHussle Ok, but `ng-model-options` was not around in v1.2.